# Problem with fancyref, babel and equation references

Tags: cross-referencing, equations, babel, fancyref

I am using fancyref and babel together in a LaTeX document and redefine the label for the equation references by `\renewcommand{\frefeqname}{Eq.}`, so that they look something like "Eq. (3.4)". However, when I have a foreign language section somewhere like `\begin{otherlanguage}{german} ... \end{otherlanguage}` then `\frefeqname` is reset to its default value for English, namely `equation`. Of course, I can redefine `\frefeqname` afterwards again, but is quite ugly and I would prefer a clean solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `babel` package uses `\caption<language>` to change the caption texts. This macro
is called in `\selectlanguage` or environment `otherlanguage`. Therefore the redefinitions should be placed in these language macros. It can be done by `babel`'s `\addto`:

```
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand*{\frefeqname}{Eq.}%
}
```

Or the interface of package `fancyref` can be used, it provides `\fancyrefaddcaptions` for this purpose, see the [documentation of `fancyref`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyref/fancyref.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german,english]{babel,fancyref}

\fancyrefaddcaptions{english}{%
  \renewcommand*{\frefeqname}{Eq.}%
}
\fancyrefaddcaptions{german}{%
  \renewcommand*{\frefeqname}{Gl.}%
}

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \fref{eq:einstein} and \fref{eq:velocity}.
  \begin{equation}
    E=mc^2 \label{eq:einstein}
  \end{equation}
\begin{otherlanguage}{german}
  \fref{eq:einstein} und \fref{eq:velocity}.
  \begin{equation}
    v=\frac st \label{eq:velocity}
  \end{equation}
\end{otherlanguage}
  \fref{eq:einstein} and \fref{eq:velocity}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Language dependent <code>\frefeqname</code>]